# How can one identify the currently clicked link with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, hyperlink

I am using Internet Explorer.

I added a context menu item (through the registry) such that when right clicking on a link in a webpage a custom menu item pops up. Upon selection, this menu item runs some javascript code.

I want to use the url of the link (on which I right click) in the javascript code - how do I access that url?

*Note that this should work for any webpage, not only ones which I have control over.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't run script on arbitrary websites. Think of the gaping security holes that would be present if you could (outside of using browser plugins and such);.

Comment: No, but this is a completely supported scenario in Internet Explorer.  It's called a context menu extension: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb735853(v=vs.85).aspx#IEAddOnsMenus_topic1 He is writing an extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  var parentwin = external.menuArguments;
  var doc = parentwin.document;
  var url = doc.URL;

  // ... the rest of your code here ...
```

See [also](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb735853%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

To get the source object, try:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  var parentwin = external.menuArguments;
  var srcElement = parentwin.event.srcElement;

  if (srcElement.tagName == "A") {
    var url = srcElement.href;

    // ... the rest of your code here ...
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. The problem with this code, is that the variable url holds the address of the current page, not the address of the link on which I right click. Any ideas? Thanks!